# UPGMA tree building in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

As a part of coursework, I had to build an UPGMA tree from a given distance matrix and a list of species names. As a beginner/intermediate in python I saw this as a good opportunity to learn about classes. The code is as follows:

```
"""
UPGMA - Unweighted pair group method using arithmetic averages
Takes as input the distance matrix of species as a numpy array
Returns tree either as a dendrogram or in Newick format
"""

#%% import modules
import numpy as np
import itertools

#%% class for nodes
class Node:
    """
    Data structure to store node of a UPGMA tree
    """

    def __init__(self, left=None, right=None, up_height=0.0, down_height=0.0):
        """
        Creating a node.
        For a single taxon, set taxon name as self.left, leave right as none.
        For an operational taxonomic unit(OTU) set left and right to child nodes.

        Parameters
        ----------
        left : default = none, taxon label
        right : default = none, taxon label
        up_height : float, default = 0.0, dist to parent node, if any
        down_height : float, default = 0.0, dist to child node, if any
        """
        self.left = left
        self.right = right
        self.uh = up_height
        self.dh = down_height

    def leaves(self) -> list:
        """
        Method to find the taxa under any given node, effectively equivalent to
        finding leaves of a binary tree. Only lists original taxa and not OTUs.

        Returns a list of node names, not nodes themselves.
        """
        if self == None:
            return []
        if self.right == None:
            return [self.left]
        leaves = self.left.leaves() + self.right.leaves()
        return leaves

    def __len__(self) -> int:
        """
        Method to define len() of a node.

        Returns the number of original taxa under any given node.
        """
        return sum(1 for taxa in self.leaves())

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        """
        Method to give readable print output
        """
        return "-".join(self.leaves())


#%% class for UPGMA
class UPGMA:
    def __init__(self, dist_matrix: np.ndarray, taxa: list):
        """
        Initialize an UPGMA class.
        Takes a nxn distance matrix as input. A list of n taxon id is required
        in the same order as the distance matrix row/column

        Parameters
        ----------
        dist_matrix : numpy array, distance matrix of species
        taxa : list of int or str to identify taxa
        """
        self.distances = dist_matrix
        self.taxa = taxa
        self.build_tree(self.distances, self.taxa)

    def build_tree(self, dist_matrix: np.ndarray, taxa: list) -> Node:
        """
        Method to construct a tree from a given distance matrix and taxa list.

        Parameters
        ----------
        dist_matrix : np.ndarray of pairwise distances
        taxa : list of taxa id. Elements of lists have to be unique

        Returns the root node for constructed tree.
        """
        # creating node for each taxa
        nodes = list(Node(taxon) for taxon in taxa)

        # dictionary row/column id -> node
        rc_to_node = dict([i, j] for i, j in enumerate(nodes))
        
        # dictionary taxa -> row/column id
        taxa_to_rc = dict([i, j] for j, i in enumerate(taxa))
        
        # make copy of dist matrix to work on
        work_matrix = dist_matrix
        # set all diagonal elements to infinity for ease of finding least distance
        work_matrix = np.array(work_matrix, dtype=float)
        np.fill_diagonal(work_matrix, np.inf)

        # loop
        while len(nodes) > 1:
            # finding (row, col) of least dist
            least_id = np.unravel_index(work_matrix.argmin(), work_matrix.shape, "C")
            least_dist = work_matrix[least_id[0], least_id[1]]
            # nodes corresponding to (row, col)
            node1, node2 = rc_to_node[least_id[0]], rc_to_node[least_id[1]]
            
            # add OTU with node1 and node2 as children. set heights of nodes
            new_node = Node(node2, node1)
            nodes.append(new_node)
            node1.uh = least_dist / 2 - node1.dh
            node2.uh = least_dist / 2 - node2.dh
            new_node.dh = least_dist / 2
            nodes.remove(node1)
            nodes.remove(node2)
           
            # create new working distance matrix
            work_matrix = self.update_distance(dist_matrix, nodes, taxa_to_rc)
            
            # update row/col id -> node dictionary
            rc_to_node = dict([i, j] for i, j in enumerate(nodes))
        # set tree to root
        self.tree = nodes[0]

    def update_distance(
        self, dist_matrix: np.ndarray, nodes: list, taxa_to_rc: dict
    ) -> np.ndarray:
        """
        Method to make a new distance matrix with newer node list.

        Parameters
        ----------
        dist_matrix : np.ndarray of pairwise distances for all taxa
        nodes : list of updated nodes
        taxa_to_rc : dict for taxa -> row/col id

        Returns np.ndarray of pairwise distances for updated nodes
        """
        # dictionary for node -> row/col id
        node_to_rc = dict([i, j] for j, i in enumerate(nodes))
        
        rc = len(nodes)
        new_dist_matrix = np.zeros((rc, rc), dtype=float)
        for node1 in nodes:
            row = node_to_rc[node1]
            for node2 in nodes:
                node_pairs = list(itertools.product(node1.leaves(), node2.leaves()))
                col = node_to_rc[node2]
                new_dist_matrix[row, col] = sum(
                    dist_matrix[taxa_to_rc[i], taxa_to_rc[j]] for i, j in node_pairs
                ) / len(node_pairs)
        np.fill_diagonal(new_dist_matrix, np.inf)
        return new_dist_matrix


def tree_to_newick(t) -> str:
    """
    Function to convert tree to Newick, slightly modified form of the tree.py version.
    Takes the root node of an UPGMA tree as input
    """
    if t.right == None:
        return t.left + ":" + str(t.uh)
    else:
        return (
            "("
            + ",".join([tree_to_newick(x) for x in [t.left, t.right]])
            + "):"
            + str(t.uh)
        )


#%% main
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # data from table 3 of Fitch and Margoliash, Construction of Phylogenetic trees
    taxa = ["Turtle", "Human", "Tuna", "Chicken", "Moth", "Monkey", "Dog"]
    distances = np.array(
        [
            [0, 19, 27, 8, 33, 18, 13],
            [19, 0, 31, 18, 36, 1, 13],
            [27, 31, 0, 26, 41, 32, 29],
            [8, 18, 26, 0, 31, 17, 14],
            [33, 36, 41, 31, 0, 35, 28],
            [18, 1, 32, 17, 35, 0, 12],
            [13, 13, 29, 14, 28, 12, 0],
        ]
    )
    x = UPGMA(distances, taxa).tree
    print(tree_to_newick(x))
```

Please suggest improvements where possible.